# Struts 2 encription user name and password

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, parameters, struts2

In a Struts2 application I am encrypt user name and password using JCription. When the user click the submit button I call a JavaScript function and  I submit the form with the encrypted user name and password. With in this JavaScript function I am setting the encrypted user name and password in as below in order to retrieve them and decrypt in the action class.

```
document.getElementsByName("user.login")[0].value=encryptedValue;
```

Below is JSP file where the user name and password resides,

```
<s:textfield name="user.login" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
<s:fielderror>
  <s:param value="%{'user.login'}" />
</s:fielderror>
```

The whole idea of doing above is to eliminate the hackers to inspect the user name and password in the request when post it.

The problem is once user clicks the submit button, the login and password field change to encrypted hexadecimal value in the login and password field because of my above assignment. How to achieve the same with out changing the non encrypted user name and password user initially enter in the UI?

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping values unchanged? After submitting values are useless.

Comment: but while the request processing back end, the user can see the original values he enters change

Comment: Then you should not change the values the user enter, if you change it somewhere else the you have remove those fields from submit because you wouldn't like to post unencrypted fields over the net, would you?

Comment: yes i dont want to submit the unencripted values instead want to submit the encrypted values. But i want to prevent user see this happening in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the text fields outside the form that you submitting. It should prevent this fields from submit, and the user could enter the values seeing it unchanged. In the form that you submit keep the hidden fields for each textfield and put encrypted values there before submit. You could do it `oncklick` or `onsubmit` events.

Comment: Thanks. In that case there are current struts 2 validations and if i move those two fields out of the form then those validation i have to make manually do instead of using the struts 2 validation know. But its fine if its the  way your proposed is the only way for my scenario.

Comment: Really I can't count how many scenariosses it could be here, the main idea you should not alter the user fields, then you should enter user fields outside the action form to not submit them, you could make another form that you validate on the client but not submit.

Comment: If you want to keep everything in one form, user fields and hidden fields, then before submit you could mark the user fields disabled, it should also prevent them from submit. But it's altering user fields and could be notable.